# I am getting error when creating a new excel file if the file is not exists in c#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, office-automation

```
string path = "F:\\abc\\LoadData.xlsx";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = null;

//Checking if the file is already exists

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))                    
    workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(path);         
else
    workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(path, ReadOnly: false);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet? worksheet = null;
app.Visible = false;
worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
```

When I tried to execute this code, I am getting error like below,

> Sorry, we couldn't find F:\abc\LoadData.xlsx. Is it possible it was > moved, renamed or deleted?

Here is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: if you don't have a file don't do `workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(path);`. Add doesn't need a path, `workbook = app.Workbooks.Add();` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this line, I am trying to create a new file if the LoadData file is not exists in the given path.

Comment: Use SaveAs on the Worksheet object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.saveas

Comment: Still I am getting same error at workbook.open line.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! What error do you get ? you posted your stacktrace, but not the message.

Comment: The error message is like this, "Sorry, we couldn't find F:\abc\LoadData.xlsx. Is it possible it was > moved, renamed or deleted?"

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown on the following line of code:

```
workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(path);
```

When the specified file is not found a new workbook is created. But you pass a template file path which doesn't exist. The [Workbooks.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.add) method creates a new workbook and the new workbook becomes the active workbook. The optional parameter determines how the new workbook is created. If this argument is a string specifying the name of an existing Microsoft Excel file, the new workbook is created with the specified file as a template.

So, when a file doesn't exists on the disk your code should look like that:

```
//Checking if the file is already exists

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))                    
    workbook = app.Workbooks.Add();         
else
    workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(path, ReadOnly: false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Workbook.Add method without any parameter is creating a excel file in the Documents folder with the name of Book1. But I want to create file in above mentioned folder with particular name.

Comment: You can save it to any other folder.

Comment: I am getting the error when I gave parameter as a path to this line.

Comment: Here is the message: "Sorry, we couldn't find F:\RiceMillProject\aaa123.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Can't pass the file path where to create a workbook. It is used as a template only. but such file doesn't exists and you get an exception at runtime. Please see my post for more information on that.

Comment: Please share me your post link. Is there any other way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Please see above.